# How do I alter the path of geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting salinity with depth in ggplot2, and I would like my geom_line to follow the data points along the y axis and not x axis.

This is what a sample of my data looks like:

```
Depth   Salinity
0       28.81
.25     28.93 
.5      28.92
.75     28.92
1       28.92
1.25    28.93
1.5     28.93
1.75    28.94
2       28.94
```

And this is the code I use...

```
 ggplot(YSIData,aes(Salinity.1,-Depth))+
   geom_point(aes(Salinity.1,-Depth,color="Profile 1"))+
   geom_line()
```

...to generate this graph (there are more data points in this graph past 2 meters)
[Depth vs Salinity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqB3y.png)

But I don't want the line to go from left to right, I want it to follow the points from top to bottom (aka the order in which they were collected). How would I change the way geom_line follows the path of my data points?

Comment: Have you considered `geom_path()` or `coord_flip()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 line plot order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020532/ggplot2-line-plot-order)

Answer (score 0):

If understand your question correctly, you want to reverse the x axis. Then this might do:

```
ggplot(YSIData, aes(Salinity.1, -Depth)) + geom_point(aes(...)) + geom_line() + scale_x_reverse()
```